# How to auto-sleep and auto-wake Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, automation, sleep, mac-mini

I've installed Windows Server 2008 on a Mac Mini. Now I want to put the computer to sleep and wake it up from sleep state at a scheduled time.

Are there any internal tools on Windows Server 2008 that can do this? Or maybe WOL from another computer?

Comment: I think going to sleep might have been a feature that the windows Server team though mightn't be required!